# dnf equivalent of "yum update --security"

Tags: fedora, dnf

`yum update --security` installs only security updates. I think it's an extension from the yum-security plugin.

Is there an equivalent dnf command? (dnf replaced yum in Fedora 22)

Comment: JFTR : by https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1234930 , this feature only is available in DNF 2 and upcoming Fedora 26

Comment: Now dnf upgrade --enablerepo=updates-testing --advisory=FEDORA-2019-7cafbe66ba

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=305905

```
#!/bin/bash

SECURITY_UPDATES_LIST=$( dnf --refresh -q updateinfo list sec | awk '{print $3}' )
SECURITY_UPDATES_NUM=`echo "$SECURITY_UPDATES_LIST" | sed '/^$/d' | wc -l`

if [ "$SECURITY_UPDATES_NUM" -eq 0 ]; then
  exit
fi

dnf upgrade -y $SECURITY_UPDATES_LIST
```

- **--refresh** force repo sync
- **-y** install automatically
- **SECURITY_UPDATES_NUM** refined/fixed counting method, works for 0/1/infinity

Comment: The same as one-liner in bash (`-y` and `--refresh` can be added): `up=$(sudo dnf -q updateinfo list sec | awk '{print $3}'); [[ $up ]] && sudo dnf upgrade $up`

Comment: As a one-liner alias `alias security-update="pkgs=\$(sudo dnf --refresh -q updateinfo list sec | awk '{print \$3}'); [[ \$pkgs ]] && sudo dnf upgrade -y \$pkgs"`

Answer (score 11):

You can use [dnf-automatic](http://dnf.readthedocs.org/en/latest/automatic.html) with three settings:

```
apply_updates = yes
download_updates = yes
upgrade_type = security
```

(Default configuration file is `/etc/dnf/automatic.conf`)

or using:

```
dnf updateinfo list security
```

to get all available updates, then update them manually.

Answer (score 3):

You can put the `dnf updateinfo list updates security` in a for loop on the cli or bash script.
I still highly recommend to review the security updates but you can always allow to throw in the `-y` command to `dnf update`

this is what works for me depending on some needs:

```
for i in $(dnf updateinfo list updates security | grep -Ei ^fedora | cut -d' ' -f3) ; do dnf update $i; done
```

Or a bit shorter with awk ( be aware this doesn't work with --refresh )

```
for i in $(dnf updateinfo list updates security | awk 'NR>1 {print $3}') ; do dnf update $i; done
```

for a dnf --refresh

```
for i in $(dnf updateinfo list updates security| dnf updateinfo list updates security| awk 'NR>1 {print $3}') ; do dnf update $i; done
```

Answer (score 0):

The before proposed methods didn't satisfy in my case. You can try this one and it's perhaps more perfect.
Create file with name "dnfupdate-security" then paste python lines below or
execute cmd:

cmd1:  sudo touch /usr/bin/dnfupdate-security && sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/dnfupdate-security

cmd2:  sudo gedit /usr/bin/dnfupdate-security

Next paste the python code into file 'dnfupdate-security', save it

Execution cmd:   sudo dnfupdate-security

```
#!/usr/bin/python
"""
DESCRIPTION: Check for security updates and insert all the packages into "dnf update" as argument.
"""
import os

updateList = ''; x = ''

for x in os.popen("dnf -q updateinfo list sec | awk '{print $3}'"):
    x = x.strip()
    updateList = updateList+' '+x

if x != '':
    os.system('dnf update '+updateList)
else:
    print 'No security updates available at this time!'
```

Comment: "more perfect" ?

Comment: This more perfect solution gives an IndentationError (because `import os` is in not at the beginning of the line (even if you remove the 3 leading spaces from each line). And even if I correct your inconsistent indentation, I get a SyntaxError.

Comment: Dissing old answers is not something you should do. Some people may think the same thing about  your code, i.e. it sucks.

Comment: All critique's accepted positively. I done few edits. I tested all and it should work on fedora/redhat based systems... I didn't mean to say method before didn't work but in my case sucks?! :)

Comment: so you put shell commands from Tomot's answer into python scripts changing `dnf upgrade -y` to `dnf update`. Any other substantial differences?

Comment: Indeed Im not sure what was wrong with tomot's code or it was very similar to someone else proposed from other place and it didn't work as it should. So I did it my way. But it works at least. I should probably verify tomots method first before i done my own, well...? At least we have one more method and is pyhtonian one...