# Postpone unimportant OS updates on Fedora (dnf)

Tags: fedora, upgrade, dnf

I have installed the package `texlive-scheme-full`. Occasionally, when I perform OS updates (via `dnf update`) I need to update n > 5000 packages. This sometimes takes about half an hour or longer and requires hundreds of MB of download volume.

Is there a way I can update my OS, installing only the most important updates, when I don't have the time nor the bandwidth to install everything?

By "most important" I mean packages relating to core functionality of the OS, especially kernel and security relevant packages. Especially unimportant I consider the updates of my tex-distribution.

I have noticed this related question, whose answers appeared a bit cumbersome to me:

- [dnf equivalent of "yum update --security"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/221983/17609)

Is this the only way to go?

Comment: `texlive` is *thousands* of very small packages. Updating them doesn't go into your download budget much. Primary large packages are e.g. kernel, GCC, firefox and such.

Answer (score 1):

It is weird that there is no such easy option. But your linked question describes it quite well and also does the linked forum post. The easiest way is probably to create such script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Check for and install security updates if available

security_updates=$( dnf -q updateinfo list sec | awk '{print $3}' )
if [ -n "$security_updates" ]; then
   exit
fi
dnf upgrade $security_updates
```

There is (obviously) already [RFE bugzilla](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1234930) for this, but still only discussed without implementation nor decision.